# Unable to connect configuration database after change domain

Tags: configuration

Because of unexpected reformat and upgrade to server, I now have a new AD and i have difficulty connection back to my sharepoint.

Due to AD user that i used to connect server farm changed, i cant connect to the configuration database anymore at sharepoint configuration wizard. Is there anyway that i can change the username and password to connect database just like that time i create a new farm?